# HTML tags to allow user to select multiple items and set their order

Tags: html

I have this input to allow user to select (with multiple choices) a product:

```
<select multiple="yes" name="products[]">
    <option value="wood">Wood</option>
    <option value="iron">Iron</option>
    <option value="gold">Gold</option>
    <option value="dust">Dust</option>
    <option value="food">Food</option>
</select>
```

User can select several stuff in that list, and I can get in server-side using, for instance, PHP:

```
$_GET['products'] ← array('wood', 'iron', 'food');
```

Now, I would like to allow users to specify an order for the selection they made. So, I want the user to be able to not only set the list of items to select (like a `<select multiple="yes">`) but also in which order I will treat them.
In other words, let's say a user want the list to be ordered to:

```
$_GET['products'] ← array('gold', 'iron', 'wood', 'dust');
```

Currently, using the `<select multiple="yes">` I can only ask user to unorderedly pick up items from a list but

**what's the HTML tags I should use to allow user to select multiple options and specify its order?**

I **don't** want to sort the options inside the `<select>`, I want the user to be able to tell the server in which order it should treat the selected items list.

I picked PHP example as server-side treating code (and it's the language I will use) but actually, the answer **should not** rely on server side language: I'm looking for the "html-client-side" code to use.

Comment: Is `<select multiple="yes">` correct HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer isn't exactly elegant but it get's the job done. I havn't been doing Web development long but I'm learning.

The JavaScript could be better as I'm used to jQuery (crutch I know).

Pure js (easier if you can use jQuery)

```
var products = [];

function add(val) {
    if (!contains(products, val))
    {
        products.push(val);
        document.getElementById('list').setAttribute('name', products);
    }
}

// checks if arr 'a'  has the element 'obj'
// thanks to someone at stack overflow for how to do that :)
function contains(a, obj) {
   var i = a.length;
   while (i--) {
       if (a[i] === obj) {
        return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

html

```
// add the onclick='add()' function to your html
<select id='list' multiple="yes" name="" value='heyo'>
   <option onclick='add("wood")' value="wood">Wood</option>
   <option onClick='add("iron")' value="iron">Iron</option>
   <option onClick='add("gold")' value="gold">Gold</option>
   <option onClick='add("dust")' value="dust">Dust</option>
   <option onClick='add("food")' value="food">Food</option>
</select>
```

Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TcGt5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script> 
    var jproducts = [];
    var selectCount= 0;
    function myFunction() {
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
   // test if select value already exist 
       options = select.getElementsByTagName('option'),
       for (var i=options.length; i--;) {
          if (options[i].selected) 
               selectCount +=1;
               if (function 'is_not_in_products_array') 
                    jproducts.push(options[i].value)
       }
     // remove unselected products
       for (var j=0; j< (jproducts.length-selectCount); j++;)
          jproducts.shift();
}
</script>
```

Finnaly the products array will containt only the last selected

```
<select id="myselect" multiple="yes" name="products[]" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="wood">Wood</option>
    <option value="iron">Iron</option>
    <option value="gold">Gold</option>
    <option value="dust">Dust</option>
    <option value="food">Food</option>
```